# Flutter - Exclude a widget from scrolling in a SingleChildScroldView

Tags: flutter

In Flutter I have a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Column` with many `Text` children.
Besides the `Text` children there is one `HandSignature` widget (from this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/hand_signature)).

When using your finger to draw onto the signature, it would trigger the scroll of the `SingleChildScrollView`. Which is why I need to exclude the scrolling behaviour from this widget.

Comment: wrap it with `AbsorbPointer`

Comment: @pskink This doesn't prohibit scrolling, but stops interacting / drawing on the widget in the first place

Comment: Yes, I can still scroll, even from the HandSignature. But it won't draw anymore @pskink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to lock and unlock your scroll. Add a `bool` variable that would be responsible for wether the screen should be scrollable at the moment. change its value when user interacts with signature widget and call `setState`. If scroll is locked, set `scrollPhysics` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`, otherwise it should be `null`.
For simple example I did a button that locks the scroll. You can check this snippet in `Dartpad`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(body: ScrollWithLock()),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollWithLock extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollWithLock({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScrollWithLock> createState() => _ScrollWithLockState();
}

class _ScrollWithLockState extends State<ScrollWithLock> {
  var isScrollLocked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: isScrollLocked ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : null,
      child: Column(children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text('This is scrollable'),
          ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            child: Text(isScrollLocked ? 'Locked' : 'Unlocked'),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              isScrollLocked = !isScrollLocked;
            });
          },
        ),
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text('This is scrollable'),
          ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. I wrapped the `HandSignature` with a `Listener` and set the lock to `true` in `onPointerDown` and to `false` in `onPointerUp` and `onPointerCancel`.
It does prohibit scrolling when touching and moving inside the `HandSignature`. Problem is the HandSignature does not draw anymore. `'package:hand_signature/src/signature_control.dart': Failed assertion: line 801 pos 12: 'hasActivePath': is not true.`

Comment: This is because the widget rebuilds, when the lock value changes. And inside build the controller of the HandSignature is set. I'll try to make it global and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your HandSignature with NotificationListener like this

```
child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {
   //do not bubble up the  notification
   return true;
  },
 child: HandSignature()
)
```

Comment: This does not work. Behaviour remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Change position of HandSignature to be on AlertDialog

Comment: You mean something like a button that opens an AlertDialog to enter a signature? If so, that is not what I want. I want to keep the signature widget along with other items in the column

Comment: my opinion is to make the tile clickable when it has no signature  then replace the value of click in your row of this tile

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by tile and row and clicks. Can you rephrase?

Comment: ok I mean ,don't take signature from scrolled column